# App smith connectivity with local database

Tags: postgresql, docker, appsmith

I have had an issue accessing the local database from Appsmith(docker container or signup from their website https://www.appsmith.com/).
I couldn't connect to my local database.
It sometimes says it can't connect to the specified localhost:5432 and asks me to "Failed to initialise pool. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections" How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:
Actually, one has to tunnel the local database and the Appsmith using tools such as ngrok(ngrok is a cross-platform application that enables developers to expose a local development server to the Internet with minimal effort. The software makes your locally-hosted web server appear to be hosted on a subdomain of ngrok.com) And use that URL as the hostname.

Method2:
When running both the Appsmith and database in docker containers, one has to give the hostname as your database docker container's IP address.